# Subpage Links with image and text

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I try to implement a page which contains images to certain subpages. For each subpage, I have a seperate image. I want to display for each subpage the appropriate image "galerie_XX.png" an show the name of the subpage above the image. So far I got:

```
galerielabel = HMENU
  galerielabel.special = directory
  galerielabel{
    1 = TMENU
    1.NO.stdWrap{
      wrap = <img src="fileadmin/templates/images/galerie/galerie_|.png" /> 
  }
 }
```

The Subpages are year names, like 2012, 2013... This script shows me the required images as a link.

My question is, how can I add the name of the subpages above the image?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested: the title of the page should be prepended

```
galerielabel = HMENU
galerielabel.special = directory
galerielabel{
    1 = TMENU
    1.NO.stdWrap{
      # Prepend with page.title
      prepend = TEXT
      prepend {
        field = title
        htmlSpecialChars = 1
      }
      wrap = <img src="fileadmin/templates/images/galerie/galerie_|.png" /> 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactely what I was looking for! Works perfectly. :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a different approach.
You can add images in the page properties.

Then, your menu could be like this:

```
lib.menu = COA
lib.menu.10 = HMENU
lib.menu.10 {
  10 = HMENU
  10.1 = TMENU
  10.1.NO.doNotShowLink = 1 #will remove the link altogether
  10.1.NO.before.cObject = COA
  10.1.NO.before.cObject {
    10 = TEXT
    10.field = title #title of the page, change to any field you like
    20 = IMAGE
    20.file.import = uploads/media/ #4.x style
    20.file.import.field = media
    20.file.import.listNum = 0 #use first image referenced
    20.width = 200 #set to imagesize of your liking
    30 = TEXT
    30.value = Do what you like here
  }
}
```